# How connect Sqlserver with visual studio by php?

Tags: php, sql-server

Can i use sqlserver database by php tool for vs??

```
<?php $server = 'AYA-PC\SQLEXPRESS';// Connect to MSSQL $link array('Database'=>'Project'); $conn=sqlsrv_connect($server,$link); if ($conn) {echo"yessssssssssssss";} else{    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));}?>
```